# Expandable Tab menu

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

everybody 
Currently i am working on Android Native App .I wish to create a expandable tab without any HTML or JavasScript file. My App is totally native App. [image]

I wish to show something like above picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can try background image for Button/image.

Set one background-1 for default, use another for hover/ click/ select effect.

Comment: Ok,,,Thanks for quick response,,,, I will  try ur suggestion